# Change ActiveMQ port in ServiceMix 4

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, esb, apache-servicemix

I'm having a problem with changing ActiveMQ port in ServiceMix.

I've set aproperiate property in /etc/system.properties:
activemq.port = 61617

Then, in etc/activemq-broker.xml I ensured that it is useing new port.
I' haven't made any further changes.
Then I've restarted/updated and refreshed all bundls in SMX4.
After that I checked my network interface with netstat and it showed that SMX 4 is using new port - 61617.

After that I've deploy my bundle (which works perfectly on default configuration of ActiveMQ)
which is adding a message to activemq, then reads it and returns enriched response.

It doesn't work and in logs i can see this error:
2013-01-10 16:02:07,519 | DEBUG | ActiveMQ Task-1  | FailoverTransport                | ?                                   ? | 49 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-core - 5.5.1 | Attempting connect to:
tcp://localhost:61616

Deleting the /data catalog produces random errors - like 'ServiceMix Util Bunlde' cannot be find - and really can't be, becouse I've to install it manualy after that kind of operation.

Any thoughts on that ?
My target is to configure ServiceMix as a Cluster via ActiveMQ. Maybe some suggestions ?